# Change different domain account without being admin Windows

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, powershell, password, accounts

I have 2 accounts on a domain.

I can log into a citrix virtual desktop with the one account fine, but the other won't let me log into anything until I first change my password.  I am remote, so I can't log into an RDP session to the servers I have access to without changing my password first.

Is it possible to change my password on my other account knowing the password but not being able to log into anything with that account?

Comment: Have a look at the following question: http://serverfault.com/questions/570476/how-can-a-standard-windows-user-change-their-password-from-the-command-line as long as you know the existing password you should be able to change it for a different user. It works on a local machine but I don't have a domain right now to test it.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can change the password on another account from a domain joined (and connected) machine.

Hit **Ctrl+Alt+Del** (if this is a remote session it might be bound to something else - according to [this link](http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/260642-ctrlaltdelete-in-desktop-in-window-mode/), Citrix Virtual Desktop uses **Ctrl+F1** when not full screen, whilst **Ctrl+Alt+End** is popular in other clients) and selecting **Change a password...** (shown below).

[image: Windows Server 2008 R2 Ctrl+Alt+Del screen]

On this screen you can change the username to the account you're looking to change the password for, and enter your old and new passwords (shown below).

[image: Windows Server 2008 R2 Change Password screen]

Assuming the machine is currently connected to a domain controller, this will work.

Answer (score 3):

Several folks here are confusing *password resets* with password changes. They are distinct in the Windows world! A password change requires knowledge of the old password, and the SELF identity has permission to Change Password on any user object, by default, in Active Directory.

A password reset is what an admin does, with no knowledge of the prior password. This requires elevated privileges. Also, password history is not enforced for password resets.

Comment: Hi @Pacific-moderate. This doesn't really answer the question, and is probably better suited to a comment on the original question - or on the answers that are getting resets and changes confused.

Answer (score -2):

If you could change the password of another account with a non-domain account then windows would be severely flawed. You need to contact your IT dept and ask them to change your password to something temporary so you can login & then change it to whatever you want.

Comment: I think you're answering someone else's question.  I have 2 domain accounts. One I can log into. The other I have a password for but have to change the password before I can log in via RDP, thus, I have a need to change it without logging in with it.

Comment: I was answering your question. If you have a domain it normally means you have an IT dept. If your password expired and you need to change it before you can login with it through RDP then you talk to your IT dept to change it for you and then allowing you to change it again once logged in. That's what I have done for many people over the years that have forgotten to change their passwords before it expired and are then calling me to help them.